# Detecting if we are in child class or base class

Tags: c++, typeid

I have a problem, and I tried to use RTTI to resolve it.

I have a class `Base` and children classes (in the example, I show only one `Child`)

```
class Base {
    virtual void Eval() {

      // normal treatment
              +
      // treatment only for Base instance
    }
};

class Child : Base {
    void Eval() {
      // call Base Eval
      Base::Eval();
      //other treatment
    }
};
```

The problem, is that in `Base::Eval`, there are some treatments which I dont't want to execute when I call it from `Child`.
What I mean, in `Child::Eval`, when we call the `Base::Eval`, we want only the normal treatment which is executed.

For this, I thought about RTTI. I don't know if it is the best way to use it, I thought to do something like this:

```
class Base {
        virtual void Eval() {

          // normal treatment
                  +
          if (typeid(this).name() == typeid(Base).name()) {         
            // treatment only for Base instance
          }
        }
    }
```

The question is: Is it permitted to do that? 
Am I obliged to check `typeid.name()`? 
Or would just `typeid()` be enough?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Situations such as this are almost always an indication of bad design. A base class should not know anything about its derived classes.

If you want to give derived classes an option to customise parts of the base behaviour, use virtual functions and the "template method" design pattern:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void Eval() {
    // normal treatment
    Eval_CustomisationHook();
  }

protected:
  virtual void Eval_CustomisationHook()
  {
    // Do the stuff
  }
};

class Child : public Base
{
protected:
  virtual void Eval_CustomisationHook()
  {} // do nothing
};
```

Alternatively, you could delegate just the query:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void Eval() {
    // normal treatment
    if (doOptionalEvalPart()) {
      // do it here
    }
  }

protected:
  virtual bool doOptionalEvalPart()
  {
    return true;
  }
};

class Child : public Base
{
protected:
  virtual bool doOptionalEvalPart()
  {
    return false;
  }
};
```

---

And to answer your original question as well: the correct form would be to compare the `std::type_info` objects, not their names. And don't forget you'd have to dereference `this`. So the code would look like this:

```
if (typeid(*this) == typeid(Base))
```

This will do what you want it to. But as I've said above, this is most probably not the proper approach.

Comment: Thx for your answer, i haven't much choice, it's an existing code, and not well designed, i agree
in fact, i can't create as you said Eval_CustomisationHook because it's just about a test (if) to make if we are in stansonly Base instance, or to not do if we are in Child instance (and of course, which contains a Base instance).
i really don't know how i will do it. I even don't know if typeid will work

Comment: @ahmedbouchaala `typeid` will work; I've re-worded the answer to make it clearer. I've also added one more way to solve this. I can't see why you couldn't do one of these.

Comment: "Template method" is not that great of a name... I've seen this pattern called "Non-Virtual Interface".

Comment: @Quentin I know it's a bad name especially in the context of C++ and its templates, but unfortunately that's the GoF name, under which many people will know it. NVI would require `Eval` to not be `virtual`.

Comment: @Angew oh, indeed. Let's roll with it then.

Comment: @Angew typeid works, and i think that is the best solution for these reasons : if we adopt your first solution, we have to change the Base::Eval call in all Children, and in for new children classes, we have to make attention about the right Eval/customisedEval to call. for me it's not a problem, but many people code on the solution and they can't resist to much modifications. for your second solution, every child solution has to put the delegated to flase, which can be forgetten by my collegues here. but for RTTI, i will touch only Base class, and others can continue working as the do usually

Comment: @ahmedbouchaala Well, good rules have even better exceptions, so if you know the `typeid` approach is the best for you, go for it. But I would be quite surprised and annoyed if I were to derive from a class, not override anything, and still get different behaviour than the base class normally exhibits.

Comment: @Angew u r right. i will make design worser with RTTI.an occasion to lean "Templat method" template. thx for all

Comment: @ahmedbouchaala If an answer solves your question, you can mark it as *accepted* by clicking the green tick-mark next to it (max. 1 accepted answer per question). This marks the question as solved and awards both you and the answerer some reputation. It's the [SO way to say "thanks"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).